# SoapUI not sending multiple attachments correctly

Tags: web-services, soapui, attachment, ready-api

I am exposing a webservice which is a questionnaire. So there are 10 questions and one attachment.
One of the question is also of type attachment. So WSDL looks like

```
<wsdl>
:
  <xs:complexType name="createUpdateAnswersheetRequestType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="answersheet" type="answersheet:answersheetType"/>
      <xs:element name="imageData" type="xsd:base64Binary"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
:
:
<xs:complexType name="answersheetType">
:
<xs:element name="imageData" type="xsd:base64Binary"/>
:
</xs:complexType>
```

I am trying to call this webservice from SoapUI. I attach two attachments through "form" view of SoapUI request. 
I am receiving only 1 file correctly on server side.

SOAP UI looks like [image]

If I send outer attachment then another attachment (answer of question) is received garbage. If I do not send outer attachment then I see another attachment (answer of question) correctly.

What is the way out ?

Comment: What does it show for `Part`, have you tried clicking there? Do you see any drop down? Are you using the request in a test case, which is necessary to show the `Part` value.

Comment: What I meant was shown in the [screen shot](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=41696619626015331919). So, the id should be matching for the respective file, then it will your service will be able to receive the correct file.

Comment: @Rao for second row when I click on "part" it shows a dropdown "v10-2.jpg" and "Anonymous".   The other options "Type" and "ContentId" are not editable.

Comment: Are you using the request in a test case? which is necessary to show the Part value.

Comment: @rao could not understand you

Comment: In your project, Have you created a test suite > test case > and test step of soap? Otherwise, you will not be able to see the `Part` value dropdown